# Using raster::rasterize's getcover to get total polygon area with overlaps

Tags: raster, r, polygon

I want to use rasterize to get how much of a raster cell is covered by polygons. This can be done like this:

```
library(raster)

p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0))
pols <- SpatialPolygons( list(  Polygons(list(Polygon(p1), Polygon(hole)), 1), Polygons(list(Polygon(p2)), 2), Polygons(list(Polygon(p3)), 3)))
pols@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]@hole <- TRUE

r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=90)

r <- rasterize(pols, r, getCover=T)

plot(r)
```

But is it possible to make getCover account for overlaps, so that the cover can exceed 100 if there are more polygons overlapping?

Answer (score 2):

Do a `rasterize` for each polygon and sum the stack:

```
> st = stack(lapply(1:length(pols), function(i){rasterize(pols[i], r, getCover=TRUE)}))
> plot(st)
> plot(sum(st))
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking in the same line. Its just... I have 400.000 polygons. But might still be the way to go.

Comment: With 400,000 you might want to do one at a time and add as you go using maybe `Reduce` or a `for` loop instead of an apply loop that makes a stack of 400,000 layers!